# Google App Engine app has no links working

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am using Google App Engine for the first time. I am trying to upload a CodeIgniter website, but the problem is no links in the website is working. Every link, even the css and js are going to the index page.

Here is my app.yaml:

```
application: vatiali-dev
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css/

- url: /js
  static_dir: js/

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts/

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your **app.yaml** to look like this:

```
application: vatiali-dev
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /css/*
  static_dir: css
- url: /js/*
  static_dir: js
- url: /fonts/*
  static_dir: fonts    
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

I have also changed threadsafe to true, unless you had it set to false for a specific reason I believe it is best practice/standard to set it to true, or else you may get performance issues.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. the css and js are working. but the links are not. if i click on a link, it is not going anywhere. It just comes to the same page. And in that page, the css and js are not working. I have updated the website. please can you check it. I am really frustated.

Comment: Load a page, view source, and show us what the links look like in their HTML form.